How to color the text within add_risktable()?
I'm trying to change the text color inside the add_risktable() function in ggsurvfit so that each strata in the risk table matches the same strata's color in the ggcuminc plot. The function in ggsurvplot that does this is risk.table.col = "strata" but I haven't figured out how to get that result to work in ggcuminc/ggsurvfit. This is my current code setup in my R shiny app.
if ("Risk Table" %in% input$rrOpt) {
        RT <- add_risktable(risktable_stats = "n.risk",
                            stats_label = list(n.risk = "Number at Risk"),
                            risktable_height = 0.3,
                            size = 4.5,
                            theme = theme_risktable_default(axis.text.y.size = 12, plot.title.size = 12))
      } else {
        RT <- NULL
      }
      
      
      rrfit <- survfit2(Surv(`Years RR from CR EOI1`, `EFS event ID`) ~ Risk, data = combined_data) %>%
        ggcuminc(outcome = 'Relapse',
                 theme = theme_minimal(),
                 size = 1,
                 linetype_aes = TRUE) +
        labs(
          x = "Years",
          y = "Cumulative Incidence"
        ) +
        coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,1)) +
        RT +
        scale_color_manual(values = palette_vector) +
        scale_linetype_manual(values = linetype_vector) +
        scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,5),
                           breaks=seq(from=0,
                                      to=5,
                                      by=1)) +
        add_legend_title(title = paste(legend_vector1, "n:", sample_vector, collapse = "\n"))
      
      if (CI == TRUE) {
        rrfit <- rrfit + add_confidence_interval()
        rrfit <- rrfit + scale_fill_manual(values = palette_vector)
      }
      else {
        rrfit <- rrfit 
      }
      
      if (!is.null(pval) && pval != FALSE) {
        pval_text <- paste(pval)
        rrfit <- rrfit + annotate("text", x = 0.1, y = 0.83, label = pval_text, size = 4, hjust = 0)
      }
      
      rrfit <- ggpar(rrfit,
                     font.x = 12,
                     font.y = 12,
                     font.caption = 12,
                     font.legend = 12,
                     font.tickslab = 12)

I've tried using the theme() function to get this to work but to no avail. The documentation for cmprsk doesn't appear to have a solution either, even though I know there must be one.
This worked with ggsurvplot
This is what ggcuminc looks like right now

I think the best option would be to raise a feature request on GH. The theme() is the wrong place to look for as it only affects the non-data ink whereas the tables are created via a geom_text. And unfortunately ´ggsurvfithas no option to map on thecoloraes in thisgeom_textlayer.  Moreover, whereasggsurvplotreturns both the main plot and the table plot as a list which allows to manipulate them, this is not the case forggsurvfit`. In the latter the table is created only in the build step when you print the plot.
